# Performance issue in giving suggestions in AutoSuggestBox in C#

Tags: c#, json, performance, autosuggest

I am making an application in C#, that uses AutoSuggestBox. I have a json file in that application, which I have deserialized into a List object. That json file is like below.

```
{"_id":690856,"name":"Tyuzler","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.083332,"lat":44.466667}}
{"_id":464737,"name":"Zaponor’ye","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":38.861942,"lat":55.639999}}
{"_id":707716,"name":"Il’ichëvka","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.383331,"lat":44.666668}}
```

It has around 2,00,000 such rows.

This is where I am facing performance issue. Since, it has 2,00,000 rows, my List object has 2,00,000 members.

When I type a letter in AutoSuggestBox, it takes 15-20 seconds to suggest something. It repeats the same after I type the next letter. So, how can I make it respond fast?

Comment: What UI platform are you using, WinForms, WPF, or UWP? Also are you loading the json file only once.?

Comment: I am using UWP. I have copied the json file into the project. I am deserializing the json and parsing it to a List<string> object after the TextChanged event is triggered.

Comment: That is what is causing your performance issue. It takes time to load the and parse the json. You should only load and parse the file on app startup if you don't expect it to change frequently. You should also take advantage of multi-threading with `Task` so that you don't lock up the UI.

Comment: So, whichever method I am using to parse the json file, I should bind it to app startup. Won't it make the app startup time to be more?

Comment: Not if you throw it on a separate/background thread.

Comment: @Nkosi Threading has also changed in Windows 10 UWP, I believe.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the help. UI is responding immediately. I have tied that method to Page_Loaded event. I will implement Task as well to improve the startup time. thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Glad you figured it out. Happy coding!!!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to help other who may stumble upon the same problem.

Comment: I will do it once I implement Task in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Instead of parsing the json file after the app starts, I am parsing it while the app starts. This helps in suggesting the options almost immediately after I type a letter in the AutoSuggestBox.

Since, I am parsing it while the app opens, the app takes 2 extra seconds to open. But that's fine since my json file is very big(almost 2,00,000 rows).